# Kubernetes load balancing between multiple deployment pods

Tags: kubernetes

in kubernetes load balancing seems to be restricted to deployments with replicas.
Well, is it possible doing load balancing between multiple pods from multiple deployments and not derived from replicas?

In short, I have 2 deployments of the same image settled down in 2 pods and I like to do loadbalancing between these two pods from cluster-ip service ?

Thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Services` do load balancing based on labels, not on `Deployments`. You can perfectly have two separate `Deployments` having a shared label and Service that points to that label. In the example below `commonLabel: test` is used as a common label. Load balancing will be performed across both `Deployments`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app1
      commonLabel: test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app1
        commonLabel: test
    spec:
      containers:
        ...
```

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app2
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app2
      commonLabel: test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app2
        commonLabel: test
    spec:
      containers:
        ...
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: commonService
spec:
  selector:
    commonLabel: test
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can connect Service to as many Deployment pods as you want by using labels:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: billing-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    component: backend      
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: billing-app
  labels:
    component: backend
    app: billing
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: checkout-app
  labels:
    component: backend
    app: checkout
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/connect-applications-service/
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

Comment: Great answer from you all. This helps a lot!